# {error: 400, reason: "Need to set a username or email", message: "Need to set a username or email [400]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am new to ReactJs, Actually I am working on Wizard form Where User will put some data in step 1 and in Step 1 we can create a user to DB and Step 2 we can upload user photo to server but when I click on next then this message is occur. 
`{error: 400, reason: "Need to set a username or email", message: "Need to set a username or email [400]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}`. Could You please help me what mistake i made in my code .

> We storing our data through API.

**Wizar Form Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './WizarStyle.css';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Steps, Form, Button, Card } from 'antd';
import RegisterStepOne from '../RegisterStepOne/RegisterStepOne';
import RegisterStepTwo from '../RegisterStepTwo/RegisterStepTwo';
import RegisterStepThree from '../RegisterStepThree/RegisterStepThree';
import RegisterStepFour from '../RegisterStepFour/RegisterStepFour';
const Step = Steps.Step;
const GeneralText = styled.div`
  color: red;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: Lato;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: #012653;
`;
const ButtonWrapper = styled.div`
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 26px;
`;
class Wizard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current: 0,
      // user: null,
    };
  }

  steps = [
    {
      title: 'General Information',
      content: (
        <RegisterStepOne
          getFieldDecorator={this.props.form.getFieldDecorator}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      title: 'Upload Photo',
      content: (
        <RegisterStepTwo
          getFieldDecorator={this.props.form.getFieldDecorator}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      title: 'Upload Resume',
      content: (
        <RegisterStepThree
          getFieldDecorator={this.props.form.getFieldDecorator}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      title: 'Add Skills',
      content: (
        <RegisterStepFour
          getFieldDecorator={this.props.form.getFieldDecorator}
        />
      ),
    },
  ];

  next() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ current: prevState.current + 1 }));
  }

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        // this.setState({ user: [this.state.user, values] });
        const userOject = {
          profile: {
            type: 'employee',
            screen: 'Step0',
          },
          ...values,
        };
        fetch('http://138.197.207.41:9000/api/auth/createuser', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            user: userOject,
          }),
        })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(user => {
            if (user.error) {
              console.warn(user);
            } else if (user && user.user) {
              console.warn(user);
              localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.user));
              const modifier = {
                id: user.user._id,
                type: user.user.profile.type,
                profile: {
                  fullName: values.fullName,
                  position: values.lastPosition,
                  username: values.username,
                  location: values.lastPosition,
                  company: values.lastCompany,
                  photo: '',
                  screen: 'Step1',
                },
              };
              fetch(`http://138.197.207.41:9000/api/auth/user/update`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  Accept: 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  id: user.user._id,
                  modifier,
                }),
              })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(res => {
                  if (res.error) {
                    console.warn(res);
                  } else {
                    console.warn(res);
                    this.next();
                  }
                })
                .done();
            }
          });
      }
    });
  };

  prev() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ current: prevState.current - 1 }));
  }

  getStep = props => this.steps[this.state.current].content;

  render() {
    const { current } = this.state;
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Card style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <GeneralText>{this.steps[current].title}</GeneralText>
          <Steps current={current}>
            {this.steps.map((item, index) => (
              <Step key={index.toString()} small="small" />
            ))}
          </Steps>
          <div className="steps-content">{this.getStep(getFieldDecorator)}</div>
          <div className="steps-action">
            {' '}
            <ButtonWrapper>
              {current < this.steps.length - 1 && (
                <Button
                  type="primary"
                  htmlType="submit"
                  style={{
                    background: '#ff9700',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    border: 'none',
                  }}
                >
                  Next
                </Button>
              )}
              {current === this.steps.length - 1 && (
                <Button
                  type="primary"
                  htmlType="submit"
                  style={{
                    background: '#ff9700',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    border: 'none',
                  }}
                >
                  Done
                </Button>
              )}
              {current > 0 && (
                <Button
                  className="preButton"
                  style={{ marginLeft: 8, border: '1px solid #ff9700' }}
                  onClick={() => this.prev()}
                >
                  Previous
                </Button>
              )}
            </ButtonWrapper>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
export default Form.create()(Wizard);
```

Comment: It seems there is some kind of validation in the server side and it is expecting username/email

Comment: @brk Yes we have some validation but we followed same process from step1 to 4 . In step 1 when i click on next data has been successfully stored and In step 2 we have image option, Image is uploaded successfully but when i click on next in step2 to move step 3 It create some error

Comment: The code you posted seems not to be relevant as it is not revealing how you create a user (`Accounts.createUser` is usually a server side method). The error you described occurs for example when `Accounts.createUser` does not receive a property named `username` or `email`.